# Getting HTTP "400" or "404" error while submitting form using Scrapy or requests module

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, python-requests

I am trying to scrape a webform and submit it, using post request with data and trying to get a response. But using Scrapy I am getting **HTTP error** code "**400**" and with requests module, I am getting "**404**" error.

Overall, I am trying to download a PDF document which shows in the browser after submitting all form details, successfully. I am trying to automate this whole workflow.

This is the [URL](https://ceo.maharashtra.gov.in/searchlist/) of a web form. Now, when you select any values from the dropdown, the form makes a POST request to the same URL with some parameters and returns a response containing HTML code. This HTML code has values of the next dropdown field. So, basically, there are two dependent dropdowns. And the selection of each dropdown, that webpage makes a POST request to itself, refresh and update the web page with the response you get from the request.

This is my code using **requests** module

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://ceo.maharashtra.gov.in/SearchList/'

response = requests.get(url, verify=False)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

headers = {    
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8",
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Content-Length": "2646",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Cookie": "ASP.NET_SessionId=wxfogxzgadg3gjxokbo0rcbn",
    "Host": "ceo.maharashtra.gov.in",
    "Origin": "https://ceo.maharashtra.gov.in",
    "Referer": "https://ceo.maharashtra.gov.in/SearchList/",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36",
}

viewstate = soup.find('input', attrs={'id' : '__VIEWSTATE'})['value']
eventvalidation = soup.find('input', attrs={'id' : '__EVENTVALIDATION'})['value']

districtList = soup.find('select', attrs={'id' : 'Content_DistrictList'}).find_all('option')[1]['value']

data = {
    '__EVENTTARGET' : 'ctl00$Content$DistrictList',
    '__EVENTARGUMENT' : '',
    '__LASTFOCUS' : '', 
    '__VIEWSTATE' : viewstate,
    '__EVENTVALIDATION' : eventvalidation,
    'ctl00$Content$DistrictList' : districtList,
    'ctl00$Content$AssemblyList' : '0',
    'ctl00$Content$PartList' : '0',
    'ctl00$Content$txtcaptcha' : ''
}

response_1 = requests.post(url, params=data, headers=headers, verify=False)

print(response_1.text)
```

And this is my code using **Scrapy**:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class ElectionSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'election'
    allowed_domains = ['ceo.maharashtra.gov.in']
    start_urls = ['https://ceo.maharashtra.gov.in/SearchList/']
    dist_dict = []

    headers = {    
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8",
        "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Content-Length": "2646",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Cookie": "ASP.NET_SessionId=wxfogxzgadg3gjxokbo0rcbn",
        "Host": "ceo.maharashtra.gov.in",
        "Origin": "https://ceo.maharashtra.gov.in",
        "Referer": "https://ceo.maharashtra.gov.in/SearchList/",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36"
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        for district in response.css('select#Content_DistrictList > option')[1:]:
            val = district.css('::attr(value)').extract_first()
            name = district.css('::text').extract_first()

            data = {
                '__EVENTTARGET' : response.css('select#Content_DistrictList::attr(name)').extract_first(),
                '__EVENTARGUMENT' : '',
                '__LASTFOCUS' : '', 
                '__VIEWSTATE' : response.css('input#__VIEWSTATE::attr(value)').extract_first(),
                '__EVENTVALIDATION' : response.css('input#__EVENTVALIDATION::attr(value)').extract_first(),
                'ctl00$Content$DistrictList' : val,
                'ctl00$Content$AssemblyList' : '0',
                'ctl00$Content$PartList' : '0',
                'ctl00$Content$txtcaptcha' : ''
            }
            meta = {'handle_httpstatus_all': True}
            print(data)
            yield scrapy.FormRequest(url=self.start_urls[0], method='POST', headers=self.headers, formdata=data, meta=meta, callback=self.parse_assembly)
            break

    def parse_assembly(self, response):
        print(response.text)
```

Now, when I am trying to make a POST request using requests and Scrapy, I get HTTP error '404' and '400' respectively. I am not able to find a solution for this issue.

So, kindly help me out here. Thanks.

**Note**: I can't use any web browser automation tools such as **Selenium** for this task.

Comment: Isn't there a CAPTCHA in the website you're trying to scrape from?

Comment: @mayankchutani, yeah and I have already done OCR part for it. But I am getting problem with filling dropdown fields with POST request.

Comment: Feels like they're detecting your cookie is not correct. It's hardcoded in your code, and they're setting it for each session.

Comment: what is the user agent you use in settings file?

Comment: it is a single scrapy file, there is no settings file. And about the user agent and cookie, I have mentioned in the header variable above in the code. I have got those header params from browser itself.

Comment: I'll try once again by creating the whole project in scrapy.

Comment: @programmerwiz32 Yeah, I have tried with scrapy project, but still same issue. This is my user agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36"

Comment: Ok, now it is working. I have removed all other 'header' variables. Edit: Also I have removed two entries from parameters.

Comment: Now, I am facing another issue. I am not able to capture the Captcha image, as this captcha image generated dynamically when we file dropdown fields which are present before the field of Captcha image. Any idea?